# Trigonometric Equation $\sin x=\tan\frac{\pi}{15}\tan\frac{4\pi}{15}\tan\frac{3\pi}{10}\tan\frac{6\pi}{15}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I solve this trigonometric equation?
$$\sin x=\tan\frac{\pi}{15}\tan\frac{4\pi}{15}\tan\frac{3\pi}{10}\tan\frac{6\pi}{15}$$

Comment: $\sin x ~=~ 1~$?

Comment: Why $\tan(\frac{\pi}{15})\tan(\frac{4\pi}{15})\tan(\frac{3\pi}{10})\tan(\frac{6\pi}{15})=1$?

Comment: I explained it in answer now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455070/proving-a-fact-tan6-circ-tan42-circ-tan12-circ-tan24-cir/455573#455573),

$$\tan x\tan(60^\circ-x)\tan(60^\circ+x)=\tan3x$$

Putting $x=12^\circ,$  $$\tan12^\circ\tan48^\circ\tan72^\circ=\tan36^\circ$$

$$\implies \tan 12^\circ \tan 48^\circ \tan 54^\circ \tan 72^\circ =\tan 54^\circ \tan36^\circ=\tan(90^\circ-36^\circ)\tan36^\circ=\cot36^\circ\tan36^\circ=1$$

Comment: @Oleg567, please have a look  into this solution?

Comment: Thanks very much. It's very well.

Comment: @Artin, my pleasure. I have prepared a list of each item containing four angles in degrees, the product of whose tangent ratios will be $1$ in the next comment. I think the formula mentioned should suffice

Comment: $$[1,59,61,87],[2,58,62,84],[3,29,31,89],[3,39,75,81],[3,57,63,81],[3,63,69,75],[4,56,64,78],[5,55,65,75],[6,28,32,88],[6,42,66,78],[6,54,66,72],[7,53,67,69],[8,52,66,68],[9,15,51,87],[9,27,33,87],[9,33,69,75],[9,51,63,69],[10,50,60,70],[11,49,57,71],[12,24,48,84],[12,26,34,86],[12,48,54,72],[13,47,51,73],[14,46,48,74],[15,21,27,87],[15,21,57,81],[15,25,35,85],[15,51,57,63],[16,42,44,76],[17,39,43,77],[18,24,36,84],[18,36,42,78],[19,33,41,79],[20,30,40,80],[21,23,37,83],[21,27,39,81],[22,24,38,82],[27,33,39,75]$$

Comment: Your work was very well. Thanks very much for posting.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there might be nicer ways to do this but here it goes. Let $\theta=\pi/15$ so you have

$$
\tan(\theta)\tan(4\theta)\tan(\frac{9}{2}\theta)\tan(6\theta)
$$

then you use $\tan()=\frac{\sin()}{\cos()}$, and then you use the equivalences

$2\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)=\cos(\alpha-\beta)-\cos(\alpha+\beta),$

and

$2\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)=\cos(\alpha-\beta)+\cos(\alpha+\beta)$.

You should get

$\frac{\cos(3\theta)\cos(\frac{3}{2}\theta)-\cos(3\theta)\cos(\frac{21}{2}\theta)-\cos(5\theta)\cos(\frac{3}{2}\theta)+\cos(5\theta)\cos(\frac{21}{2}\theta)}{\cos(3\theta)\cos(\frac{3}{2}\theta)+\cos(3\theta)\cos(\frac{21}{2}\theta)+\cos(5\theta)\cos(\frac{3}{2}\theta)+\cos(5\theta)\cos(\frac{21}{2}\theta)} $

** I also used the fact that $\cos(-\alpha)=\cos(\alpha)$. Now, note that you have something of the form

$\frac{a-b-c+d}{a+b+c+d},$

which is equal to $1+\frac{-2b-2c}{a+b+c+d}$. Now, we shall show that $-2b-2c=0$. So we have

$
-2b-2c=-2\cos(3\theta)\cos(\frac{21}{2}\theta)-2\cos(5\theta)\cos(\frac{3}{2}\theta)
$

using the formula above for the product of cosines we get

$-2\cos(3\theta)\cos(\frac{21}{2}\theta)-2\cos(5\theta)\cos(\frac{3}{2}\theta)=-\cos(\frac{15}{2}\theta)-\cos(\frac{27}{2}\theta)-\cos(\frac{7}{2}\theta)-\cos(\frac{13}{2}\theta).$

Now plug in the value of $\theta$, you get

$
-\cos(\pi/2)-\cos(\frac{27}{30}\pi)-\cos(\frac{7}{30}\pi)-\cos(\frac{13}{30}\pi)
$

naturally the first element is $0$. Now, using the fact that $\cos(\alpha\pm\pi/2)=\mp\sin(\alpha)$ you can write

$
-\cos(\frac{27}{30}\pi)-\cos(\frac{7}{30}\pi)-\cos(\frac{13}{30}\pi)=\sin(6\pi/15)-\sin(\frac{4}{15}\pi)-\sin(\pi/15)
$

Now you use $\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)=\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)}{2}$ looking for two numbers such that the equality holds. You should get then

$
\sin(6\pi/15)-\sin(\frac{4}{15}\pi)-\sin(\pi/15)=\sin(6\pi/15)-2\sin(\pi/6)\cos(\pi/10)=\sin(6\pi/15)-\cos(\pi/10)
$

which it is easily seen to be zero.

Therefore

$
\tan(\theta)\tan(4\theta)\tan(\frac{9}{2}\theta)\tan(6\theta)=1, \qquad \theta=\pi/15
$

Answer (score 3):

Put $z = \exp(i\pi/30)$ and use Euler's formula to get
$$P = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{15}\right)
\times \tan\left(\frac{4\pi}{15}\right)
\times \tan\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)
\times \tan\left(\frac{6\pi}{15}\right) \\
= \frac{1}{i^4}
\frac{z^2-1/z^2}{z^2+1/z^2}
\frac{z^8-1/z^8}{z^8+1/z^8}
\frac{z^9-1/z^9}{z^9+1/z^9}
\frac{z^{12}-1/z^{12}}{z^{12}+1/z^{12}} \\
= 
\frac{z^4-1}{z^4+1}
\frac{z^{16}-1}{z^{16}+1}
\frac{z^{18}-1}{z^{18}+1}
\frac{z^{24}-1}{z^{24}+1}.$$
Now simplify moving from right to left, repeatedly applying the fact that $z^{30}=-1$.
First we get
$$
\frac{z^4-1}{z^4+1}
\frac{z^{16}-1}{z^{16}+1}
\frac{z^{42}-z^{18}-z^{24}+1}{z^{42}+z^{18}+z^{24}+1}
= \frac{z^4-1}{z^4+1}
\frac{z^{16}-1}{z^{16}+1}
\frac{-z^{12}-z^{18}-z^{24}+1}{-z^{12}+z^{18}+z^{24}+1}$$
This is
$$\frac{z^4-1}{z^4+1}
\frac{-z^{28}-z^{34}-z^{40}+z^{16}+z^{12}+z^{18}+z^{24}-1}
{-z^{28}+z^{34}+z^{40}+z^{16}-z^{12}+z^{18}+z^{24}+1}$$
which is in turn
$$\frac{z^4-1}{z^4+1}
\frac{-z^{28}+z^4+z^{10}+z^{16}+z^{12}+z^{18}+z^{24}-1}
{-z^{28}-z^4-z^{10}+z^{16}-z^{12}+z^{18}+z^{24}+1}.$$
Call this fraction $f.$ We need to show that $f=1.$ The numerator is
$$ -z^{32}+z^8+z^{14}+z^{20}+z^{16}+z^{22}+z^{28}-z^4\\
+ z^{28}-z^4-z^{10}-z^{16}-z^{12}-z^{18}-z^{24}+1$$
The denominator is
$$ -z^{32}-z^8-z^{14}+z^{20}-z^{16}+z^{22}+z^{28}+z^4\\
-z^{28}-z^4-z^{10}+z^{16}-z^{12}+z^{18}+z^{24}+1.$$
The difference between these two is
$$2\times \left(z^{28}-z^{24}-z^{18}+z^{14}+z^8-z^4\right)
= 2\times \left(z^{28}-z^{24}+1/z^{12}-1/z^{16}+z^8-z^4\right).$$
Now putting $u = z^4 = \exp(4 i\pi/30) = \exp(2i\pi/15)$ this becomes
$$2\times \left(u^7-u^6+1/u^3-1/u^4+u^2-u\right).$$
But $u^5 = -1/2 + 1/2\sqrt{3}i$ and  $u^{-5} = -1/2 - 1/2\sqrt{3}i$ so the inner term finally becomes
$$\left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}i\right) u^2 
- \left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}i\right) u 
+ \left(-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}i\right) u^2
- \left(-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}i\right) u\\ + u^2 -u$$
which is
$$u^2\left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}i 
-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}i +1\right)+
u\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}i
+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}i -1\right) = 0.$$
This means that the difference between numerator and denominator of $f$ is zero and since both are nonzero we have $f=1$ as desired.

The motivation for this admittedly somewhat tedious calculation is that it demonstrates how a computer algebra system might carry out this sort of simplification without human intervention.

There is a more creative use of the above techniques at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455995/finding-the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-cos-frac-x-2-cdot-cos-frac).

Answer (score 2):

Let's use degree measure (for writing convenience):
we need to prove identity
$$
\tan 12^\circ \tan 48^\circ \tan 54^\circ \tan 72^\circ = 1.\tag{1}
$$

$$
\sin 12^\circ \sin 48^\circ \sin 54^\circ \sin 72^\circ =^?= \cos 12^\circ \cos 48^\circ \cos 54^\circ \cos 72^\circ;\tag{2}
$$

$$
\sin 12^\circ \sin 48^\circ \sin 54^\circ \sin 72^\circ =^?= \sin 78^\circ \sin 42^\circ \sin 36^\circ \sin 18^\circ;
$$

$$
(\sin 12^\circ \sin 72^\circ ) \cdot ( \sin 48^\circ \sin 54^\circ) =^?= (\sin 18^\circ \sin 78^\circ ) \cdot ( \sin 36^\circ \sin 42^\circ);
$$

$$
(\cos 60^\circ - \cos 84^\circ)(\cos 6^\circ - \cos 102^\circ) =^?=
(\cos 60^\circ - \cos 96^\circ)(\cos 6^\circ - \cos 78^\circ);
$$

$$
(\cos 60^\circ - \cos 84^\circ)(\cos 6^\circ + \cos 78^\circ) =^?=
(\cos 60^\circ + \cos 84^\circ)(\cos 6^\circ - \cos 78^\circ);
$$

$$
-\cos 84^\circ \cos 6^\circ + \cos 60^\circ \cos 78^\circ =^?=
\cos 84^\circ \cos 6^\circ - \cos 60^\circ \cos 78^\circ;\tag{3}
$$

$$
\cos 84^\circ \cos 6^\circ - \cos 60^\circ \cos 78^\circ=^?=0.\tag{4}
$$

Yes, $(4)$ is true  identity, because
$$
2\sin 6^\circ \cos 6^\circ = \sin 12^\circ,
$$

$$
\sin 6^\circ \cos 6^\circ = \frac{1}{2}\sin 12^\circ,
$$
$$
\cos 84^\circ \cos 6^\circ = \cos 60^\circ \cos 78^\circ.\tag{5}
$$

So, we get equation

$$
\sin (x) = 1. \tag{6}
$$

Solution is obvious...