# Anybody know a proof of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\cos(x/2^n)=\sin x/x$.

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

This is actually an exercise from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis. Ch. 8 Ex 42. which asks to find all real values $x$ for which $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \cos\left(\large\frac{x}{2^n}\right)$ converges. I've shown that the product converges for all $x$. The problem then asks to find what values the product converges to. By playing around with Wolfram Alpha, I found that
$$\large\prod_{n=1}^\infty\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=\frac{\sin (x)}{x}.$$

I can't figure out how to prove this.

Comment: It has the correct set of zeroes, hence the quotient is an entire analytic function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the limit $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\ (\cos \frac x 2 \cdot\cos \frac x 4\cdot \cos \frac x 8\cdots \cos \frac x {2^n}) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455995/finding-the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-cos-frac-x-2-cdot-cos-frac)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using the trig identity

$$\sin (2t) = 2\sin (t) \cos (t),$$

we have

$$\prod_{n = 1}^N \cos(x/2^n) = \prod_{n = 1}^N \frac{\sin(x/2^{n-1})}{2\sin(x/2^n)} = \frac{\sin(x)}{2^N\sin(x/2^N)} = \frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot \frac{x/2^N}{\sin(x/2^N)}$$

Take the limit as $N \to \infty$ and use the fact $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin t}{t} = 1$ to obtain the result.

Comment: I'm not the OP, so feel free to ignore this request, but I'm lost on the argument that $\lim_{N\to\infty} 2^N \sin(2^{-N}x) = x$

Comment: @jameselmore By the Taylor expansion we have $\sin(2^{-N}x)\sim_{N\to\infty}2^{-N}x$.

Comment: @jameselmore I've added more details. Since $(\sin t)/t \to 1$ as $t \to 0$, $(\sin x/2^N)/(x/2^N) \to 1$ as $N \to \infty$. Therefore $(x/2^N)/\sin(x/2^N) \to 1$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: @kobe, Thanks! Makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

$$\cos(x/2^n)=\frac12\frac{\sin(x/2^{n-1})}{\sin(x/2^n)}$$
and telescope.

Comment: How do you incorporate the denominator $x$ into your proof?