# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{1-\tan^2(2^{-n})}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{1-\tan^2(2^{-n})}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $p_{k} = \displaystyle \frac{1}{1-\tan^2(2^{-n})} = \frac{\cos^2(2^{-k})}{\cos(2^{-k+1})}$

So $\displaystyle p_{1}p_{2}p_{3}...........p_{n} = \frac{\cos^2(2^{-1})}{\cos(2^{0})}\cdot \frac{\cos^2(2^{-2})}{\cos(2^{-1})}\cdot \frac{\cos^2(2^{-3})}{\cos(2^{-2})}\cdot.........\frac{\cos^2(2^{-n})}{\cos^2(2^{-n+1})}$

Now How can I solve after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Which is correct $1/\tan^2(2^{-n})$ (in the title) or $1/(1-\tan^2(2^{-n}))$ (in the body)?

Comment: You can obviously do some cancelling.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455995/finding-the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-cos-frac-x-2-cdot-cos-frac

Comment: @mathlove I think its $1-\tan^2(2^{-n})$ or else $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=undefined$

Comment: In addition to telescoping sum, there is something called telescoping product. this is one example of it.

Comment: You mean $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-\tan^2(2^{-k})}$ ? Then look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455995/finding-the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-cos-frac-x-2-cdot-cos-frac?lq=1 .