# Is there a closed form for $3\cdot\frac{3}{\sqrt{6}}\cdot\frac{3}{\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6}}}\cdot\frac{3}{\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6}}}}\cdots$?

Tags: closed-form, infinite-product, nested-radicals

Inspired by Vieta's Formula for $\pi$,
$$\pi=2\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}\cdots$$
I became interested in a more generalized case for Vieta's Formula.

> For $m=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\cdots}}}}$, what is the closed form of 
>   $$m\cdot\frac{m}{\sqrt{a}}\cdot\frac{m}{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}\cdot\frac{m}{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}}\cdots$$?

To find the value of $m$, we can solve the following equation
$$m=\sqrt{a+m}$$,
which gives
$$m=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$$

One example is that
$$3=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\cdots}}}}$$
And I want to find the exact value of 
$$3\cdot\frac{3}{\sqrt{6}}\cdot\frac{3}{\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6}}}\cdot\frac{3}{\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6}}}}\cdots\approx3.815$$
but to no avail. Could anyone provide any insight on the possible closed form for this infinite product?

Comment: @heepo:  Huh???  That number is zero.

Comment: Why not show insight into the problem and divide by $3$ throughout?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I see three favorites and one upvote, Also, more related: the meat of this question is probably concerned with finding $P_n = \sqrt{a+\sqrt{a\dots}}$ where $a$ appears $n$ times. I doubt there's an explicit formula for this, but a recursive one might give you something.

Comment: I see $0$ favorites.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but I am surprised at how many users favorite questions without upvoting.

Comment: Re: number of favorites -- it doesn't update without you reloading the page.

Comment: The limit of the $n$-th term in that product is $\dfrac{m}{\sqrt{a+1/4}+1/2}$. So if $m > \sqrt{a+1/4}+1/2$, the product grows without bound, and if $m < \sqrt{a+1/4}+1/2$, the product tends to $0$. So only the case where $m =  \sqrt{a+1/4}+1/2$ remains.

Comment: One of the reasons why the first product has a simple closed form is that $2x^2-1$ is a Chebyshev polynomial. The more general case of quadratic recurrence with closed-form solutions is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function), which seems to imply that it's very hard to find a closed form of the second product.

Comment: @heepo I use the Favourite function as an easy way to bookmark a question I'm interested in seeing answered. If I don't think it's an especially good question for whatever reason I won't upvote it.

Comment: An interesting sub-question: just for the hell of it, define $$\Pi(a)=\prod_{n\ge0}\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2q_n(a)}$$ where $q_{n+1}(a)=\sqrt{a+q_n(a)}$ and $q_0(a):=1$. Of course we see that $\Pi(2)=\pi$, **but what is $\Pi(1)$?** I take interest in this particular case, because it would involve everyone's favorite number, the golden ratio $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$. Perhaps the $\Pi(1)$ product, being a product of powers of $\varphi$, can be rephrased in terms of Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Just a comment, as the comment section is really getting long, you may really want to know the connection why it is $2$ in the radical that gives this amazing result. It is due to it's connection to trigonometric functions. More specifically, a quick research into this can give that a result, ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455995/finding-the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-cos-frac-x-2-cdot-cos-frac))
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\cos \frac{x}{2}\cdot\cos \frac{x}{4}\cdot\cos \frac{x}{8}...$$
And also the fact that
$$\cos\frac{x}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...(n-1) times}}}$$
or more specifically speaking;
$$A=\frac{\sin A}{\cos\frac{A}{2}\cdot \cos\frac{A}{4}\cdot \cos\frac{A}{8}...}$$
So a generalized version of this would be doubtful. And also one can obviously make a conjecture that that your stated problem will result in a transendental number which couldn't be expressed in terms of closed form algebraic numbers or functions.

A very good paper, if you're really interested in square roots will be [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06139.pdf), by Dixon J. Jones