# Study the following sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, pi

I am having trouble studying the following sequence $(x_k)_{k \geq 2}$ :

$$x_2= 2, \quad x_{k+1}= \frac{x_k}{\cos{(\pi 2^{-k})}}$$

I want to show that this sequences converges to $\pi$, but I have honestly no idea where to start.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://math.stackexchange.com/q/455995/399263

Comment: Thank you ! It is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Voting to close as answered in [the link found by @zwim](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455995/finding-the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-cos-frac-x-2-cdot-cos-frac).